# How to run streaming query on updated lines in CSV file?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have one csv file in a folder that is keep on updating continuously. I need to take inputs from this csv file and produce some transactions. How can I take data from the csv file that is keep on updating , lets say every 5 minutes?

I have tried with following:

```
val csvDF = spark
  .readStream
  .option("sep", ",")
  .schema(userSchema)
  .csv("file:///home/location/testFiles")
```

but the issue is it is monitoring the folder that any new files has been created or not... but my issue is only one file that is keep on updating.

Answer (score 3):

> I have 1 csv file in 1 folder location that is keep on updating everytime. i need to take inputs from this csv file and produce some transactions. how can i take data from csv file that is keep on updating , lets say every 5 minutes.

**tl;dr** It won't work.

Spark Structured Streaming by default monitors files in a directory and for every new file triggers a computation. Once a file has been processed, the file will never be processed again. That's the default implementation.

You could write your own streaming source that could monitor a file for changes, but that's a custom source development (which in most cases is not worth the effort yet doable).

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, I'm not sure how you arrive here, because a csv file should be written sequencially, which is able to achieve a better Input/Output. So my recommendation is that you create an append-only file, and try to get the stream data like getting data from binlog.

However if you have to do this, I think StreamingContext may help you.

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(new SparkConf(), Durations.milliseconds(1))
val fileStream = ssc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat]("/tmp", (x: Path) => true, newFilesOnly = false).map(_._2.toString)
```

Comment: `StreamingContext` is part of Spark Streaming, but the OP uses Spark Structured Streaming. Two different streaming Spark modules.